# C++ STL map update all of the values at the same time

Tags: c++, stl

I need to update all the values (integers) of a map in C++. All the values are going to be multiplied by a float (0.30), so no need to do it one by one.

I can do it manually but I want to know if there is a way to multiply them all at once.

```
map < string, int >ouremployees = {

    {"Haaziq", 80000},
    {"Aldo", 100000},
    {"Monte", 30000},
    {"Carlo", 20000},
    {"Afif", 50000},

   // THERE ARE MORE WAY WAY MORE BUT ALL THE INT NUMBERS/ VALUES NEED TO BE //MULTIPLIED BY .30 ALL OF THEM

  };
```

Comment: This is what loops are for.  If you don't want to hand roll the loop, use `std::for_each` and a lambda.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you multiply all the numbers by 0.30 and re-store them in the map they will be truncated (vs. rounded) unless you address this specifically. This won't affect the particular values you have here, but could be an issue for other arbitrary doubles and initial values.

Comment: *I can do it manually but I want to see a way to multiply them all in one instruction* By that do you mean one line of code or one line of machine instruction?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

Comment: A better design would be to have your own class that wraps both a map<string,int> and a float scaling factor. When you read-access it, you multiply by the scaling factor. When you want to update the scaling factor, you just adjust the float value.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks a lot indeed!

In the end I ended up doing it like this:

```
int salary_it; // this var will hold salaries
string name_it;// THIS VARIABLE WILL HOLD THE KEY , EITHER FOOD NAME OR EMPLOYEE NAME
//we change all salaries
map < string, int >::iterator it3b;
  for (it3b = ouremployees.begin (); it3b != ouremployees.end (); it3b++)
    {
      salary_it=it3b->second;
      name_it=it3b->first;
      cout<<name_it<<"       "<<salary_it<<endl;
      //NOW WE CAN  EITHER USE A find, or [], since the key is being retrived from the 
      //map itself then there is no risk in using the []
     ouremployees[name_it]=salary_it+=salary_it*.30;//instead of .30 we can ask for percentage
    }
```

Comment: Duh! This is a lot more convoluted than it needs to be. You could replace the entire loop body with `it3b->second *= 0.3;`. Or, as Vlad suggested, you replace the entire loop with `for (auto &p : ouremployees) p.second *= 0.3;`.

Comment: HolyBlackCat   I know, but I also need to explian it, so it is easier to explain as it has all the steps...

Comment: It's really wasteful to do a new lookup, when `it3b->second` already gives you access to the value (you used it for read, but it also works fine for write).

Answer (score 5):

In any case you have to do this "manually".:)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map <std::string, int> ouremployees = 
    {
        { "Haaziq", 80000 },
        { "Aldo", 100000 },
        { "Monte", 30000 },
        { "Carlo", 20000 },
        { "Afif", 50000 },
    };

    double multiplier = 0.3;

    for ( auto &p : ouremployees ) p.second *= multiplier;

    for ( const auto &p : ouremployees ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Afif 15000
Aldo 30000
Carlo 6000
Haaziq 24000
Monte 9000
```

Instead of the range-based for loop you could for example use standard algorithm `std::for_each`.

Fro example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::map <std::string, int> ouremployees = 
    {
        { "Haaziq", 80000 },
        { "Aldo", 100000 },
        { "Monte", 30000 },
        { "Carlo", 20000 },
        { "Afif", 50000 },
    };


    std::for_each( std::begin( ouremployees ), std::end( ouremployees ),
                   [multiplier = 0.3]( auto &p ) { p.second *= multiplier; } );

    for ( const auto &p : ouremployees ) std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that maybe the second template argument of the map should be declared as the type argument `double`.

Comment: Maybe also mention `std::transform` and `std::apply` :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl It seems std::transform is not suitable in this situation.

Comment: Why not? You could transform the container into a new one containing multiplied values. That new container could then (optionally) be used to replace the original.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It is not an efficient approach.

Comment: No. I agree. Not the most efficient. But it *is* an option - and a very readable one. And sometimes (often) that's good enough and the inefficiency doesn't *actually* matter.